# How to Delete a Contact's "Mark as Default" selection

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-5

In the stock Contacts app one can `Mark as default` one of the contact's numbers. I don't want to select another number as default, *I don't want any of the contact's numbers to be default.*

**How can I delete this "mark as default" selection?**

I have a Samsung Galaxy S5 running Lollipop 5.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is the following:

1. Open the contact
2. There will be a check mark indicating the default number: Press and hold on that number
3. A box will appear. Select **Remove Default**
   (this may also be **Clear default**)

You can also mark a number as default by pressing down on the phone number and selecting **Mark as Default**

Comment: I have no checkmark, but holding the number opens a menu with "Clear default". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no functionality to "unmark" the default setting for a contact.  However this work around will remove the "mark as default" setting for a phone entry:

1. Edit the contact
2. Add a new phone number using the same number as the entry currently marked as default

   Note:  You will need to temporarily choose a different phone number type (e.g. work) for the new entry
3. Delete the phone entry marked as default
4. Save the contact. When prompted to mark an entry as default, touch `Cancel`
5. Edit the contact a second time
6. Change the new phone entry's "type" back to its original setting

Tested on Lollipop 5.0 using the built-in Contacts app.